# How to take the NSuserdefaults value in a constant class?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have an application in which i have a constants.h class ,which has some predefined values.as

```
#define #define PUSHER_API_KEY@""
#define PUSHER_API_SECRET @""
#define PUSHER_APP_ID     @""
```

and an authentication url 
`#define PRESENCE_AUTH_URL @"http://hdjhjf.com/presence-auth.php?uid=11&mdid=14"`where the uid and mdid i need to be dynamic.so i need to take it from userdefaults.but in that constant.h class how can i use that.when i try to use it it is giving me an error that initiliser is not a compile time constant.I have to change this Hardcoded 11&14 to dynamic values.Can anybody help me?

Comment: cna you post the code of your error?

Comment: its becoz i am doing that code before the scope.i got it.But my problem is i need to change this 11 and 14 to dynamic values.can u pls help me in that?

Comment: you can define a userDefault, like this #define PUSHER_API_KEY [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"APIValue"]; but be careful because the value of that variable will be the same if you don't refresh the view with the class. I think is better to create a singleton class for get the value of the session.

Comment: How is a constants header a good place for a dynamically calculated value from NSUserDefaults?

Comment: why don't create a object with .m and .h files? you can have a bool property for static or dinamic and get the value of your variable. In .m if the bool is static, return the string of #define, if is dinamic return the value of nsuser defaul

Answer (score 0):

If you are desperate to have this as a `#define` statement. Then you could do this.

```
#define PRESENCE_AUTH_URL [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://hdjhjf.com/presence-auth.php?uid=%@&mdid=%@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"UDIDKey"], [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"MDIDKey"]]
```

It looks like you are using libPusher you may be able to set the auth url this way too.

```
pusher.authorizationURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://hdjhjf.com/presence-auth.php?uid=%@&mdid=%@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"UDIDKey"], [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"MDIDKey"]];
```

Comment: this is fine,but i have to be done it in the constant.h class which has only some #define statements only.

Comment: Is there a reason it *has* to be in constant.h? If you need to pull from `NSUserDefaults` you won't be able to do it with a `#define` statement. `#define` statements are evaluated during the build, they cannot be changed later in code.

Comment: it needs to be there as it is the requirement of the api.I am asking how we can do this in #define PRESENCE_AUTH_URL @"http://fdgsfdgfs.com/presence-auth.php?udid=%@&mdid=%@"like this

Comment: A quick google shows that you are probably using libPusher, that information would be helpful in the question. See my edit of the answer.